# Allow the user to change their own JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm teaching students how to write JavaScript, so I've got this on the page:

```
<textarea name="PgmJS">console.log(1);</textarea>
<script id="PgmJS">
</script>
```

What I'd like to do is:

```
$('textarea[name=PgmJS]').on('keyup',PgmJSKeyUp);
function PgmJSKeyUp() {
    $('#PgmJS').text('function init() {' + $(this).val() + '}');
    init();
}
```

But the browser is saying that init() is not defined.

Comment: And where did you define it? All you did was to set the text of some textarea.

Comment: Why not just `eval()` it? Or use `var init = new Function(this.value);`

Comment: Forgive me for saying but I worry for your students 7;^)

Comment: @norlesh lol.  Yeah.  What we're going to do is deconstruct a game.

Answer (score 5):

It doesn't work this way, you need the evil `eval`:

```
function PgmJSKeyUp() {
    eval($(this).val());
}
```

You could also use `Function`, `setTimeout` or `setInterval` (if you clear it), which are as evil as `eval` when used with strings.
Or, if you really want to use `<script>` element,

```
function PgmJSKeyUp() {
    var $s = $('<script type="text/javascript">');
    $s.text($(this).val());
    $('body').append($s);
}
```

But keep in mind that JS code inside `<script>` elements is only executed when they are added to the document.

Comment: I think I need to remove the original js first though, and issuing a $('#PgmJS').remove() doesn't seem to do it.

Comment: It removes when I look at $('#PgmJS'), but the program is still running merrily along despite it not being in the dom.

Comment: I think it's because it's on a setInterval, so removing it from the dom might not have removed it from memory.

Comment: @Phillip Yes, removing a `<script>` element doesn't undo nor stop its code. If you want to stop a `setInterval`, you need `clearInterval`

Answer (score 2):

That's because you're specifying the init function inside the textarea's text property - which by default, does not get picked up by the browser's JS compiler.

You will need to define the init function as normal JS code, and execute the custom JS code inside it. I smell an eval() coming on (ugh!) :|